# How to deploy only zip artifacts in maven

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-deploy-plugin

I have done some zip packaging in maven using the below descriptor and pom file. But in maven by default it created both jar and zip in target folder. Now i want to deploy only zip contents where i am using deploy:deploy-file plugin. but it is not deploying instead it is showing error. Not sure what is wrong with tag and how it should be resolved.

Pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.wyndhamvo.prototype.dbscripts</groupId>
  <artifactId>DB_SCRIPTS</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0.1</version>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptor>src/assembly/descriptor.xml</descriptor>
            </configuration>
            <executions> 
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>wvoNexus</id>
        <file>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.zip</file>
        <url>http://nexus.corproot.com/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>

    <repository>
        <id>wvoNexus</id>
        <file>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.zip</file>
        <url>http://nexus.corproot.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>

</project>
```

assembly plugin descriptor file:

```
<assembly>
<formats>
    <format>zip</format>
</formats>

<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*</include>
        </includes>
        <outputDirectory>DB_Files</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Command Executed:

```
mvn -X clean package deploy:deploy-file
```

Error:

```
[ERROR] Malformed POM C:\Divakar\MavenPrototype\DB_Maven_Test\dev\pom.xml: Unrecognised tag: 'file' (position: START_TAG seen ...<id>wvoNexus</id>\r\n\t\t\t<file>... @37:10)  @ C:\Divakar\MavenPrototype\DB_Maven_Test\dev\pom.xml, line 37, column 10
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First you have to fix you error in distributionManagement area like this:

```xml
  <distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>wvoNexus</id>
        <url>http://nexus.corproot.com/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>

    <repository>
        <id>wvoNexus</id>
        <url>http://nexus.corproot.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
```

If you fixed that you can simple deploy the files to your nexus via:

```
mvn clean deploy
```

If you don't like having a jar deployed as well you need to change the packing type in your pom like this:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.wyndhamvo.prototype.dbscripts</groupId>
  <artifactId>DB_SCRIPTS</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0.1</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptor>src/assembly/descriptor.xml</descriptor>
                </configuration>
                <executions> 
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Furthermore i recommend to define the versions of your used plugins like this:

```xml
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptor>src/assembly/descriptor.xml</descriptor>
                </configuration>
                <executions> 
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Thank you @khmarbaise. it worked. but didnt deploy in snapshot repository. `http://nexus.corproot.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/wynd
hamvo/prototype/dbscripts/DB_SCRIPTS/2.0.0.1/DB_SCRIPTS-2.0.0.1.zip (3 KB at 63.
8 KB/sec)`

Comment: Of course not cause you defined a release version and *NOT* a SNAPSHOT version.

Comment: Sorry. coudlnt get you. i defined both release and snapshot in distributionManagement tag. still do i need to define somewhere? or something wrong in my pom file.

Comment: You defined in your `<version>2.0.0.1</version>` which is a release version from Mavne point of view. If you like having a SNAPSHOT you need to define `<version>2.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>attach-artifacts</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <artifacts>
            <artifact>
              <file>some file</file>
              <type>extension of your file </type>
              <classifier>optional</classifier>
            </artifact>
          </artifacts>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake: the `<file/>` element is not a part of `<snapshotRepository/>`, it's an config item of deploy plugin! you should deploy your zip file as following:

```
mvn -X clean package deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=/path/to/your-artifact-1.0.zip
```